# Virtual Machines with AD/DNS

Tags: virtualization

Running Win Server 2008 R2 with Hyper-V role. Is it okay to have domain controllers inside a virtual machine with other virtual machines that are part of that domain? The host computer will not be part of a domain controller. Hyper-V is configured to delay the boot up of other virtual machines to make sure the domain controller starts first.

Answer (score 5):

This is fine, but like any other environment, best practices are to have more than one Domain Controller for any given domain. Since you're virtualizing, you'll want each DC to run on more than one piece of hardware.

In VMWare you can make DRS rules so that the two DCs don't get vMotioned to the same physical box, I'm sure there a similar thing for Hyper-V. Or, if you're just using it stand-alone, pop up another DC somewhere outside of the virtual environment.

Comment: Curses... trying to answer questions on Serverfault when I know you're also online is like playing Minesweeper...

Comment: I have three physical servers. Two physical servers will run Hyper-V with one domain controller on each inside a VM. The third is just our backup server.It's a small organization, so consolidating would be better. And since it's not recommended to make a DC run more roles, this seems to fit our need best.

Comment: In Hyper-V you need to set up your Hyper-V hosts in a failover cluster and then you need to select the Possible Owners for the clustered VM to define an "affinity" rule analogous to a VMware DRS affininty rule.

Comment: I guess my biggest question is how do I properly backup the VM of the domain controller if I need to restore it at some point without messing things up. The other question is, if one physical host goes down, can the other server pick up the slack of the other virtual machines until its rebuilt. I understand performance will be slower, but I'm only running 2 virtual machines per host as it is.

Comment: @NoMoreDell4Me You should do two backups, one of the whole image and one of the system state. The full image backup will let you restore from bare metal in a disaster. The system state backup will let you do an authoritative restore of AD if you accidentally do something like delete an OU. AD Domain Services is a relatively low-load role. As long as both DCs are Global Catalogs, you shouldn't have too big of an issue if one of them is down for a short time.

Comment: @RyanRies Unfortunately for you, work is a bit slow right now :)

Comment: I use Symantec System Recovery 2011 Server Edition, it does a full backup of C:\ and the System Drive (!00MB) once every week.

Comment: I'm assuming its better to start the domain controller from scratch and run dc promo than recover from backup, as long as the other domain controller is functional, correct?

Comment: Yep. That's right. You don't want to do an authoritative restore if you don't have to.

Comment: Ok. So I'll create a VM with AD DS installed and save that file so I don't have to do all the windows updates, etc if the other VM should fail. All I'll have to do is change the IP and run dcpromo and wait for replication to happen.

Comment: How should I handle the backup of the physical host? If I backup the entire C: drive then all my VM's will be backed up with it.

Comment: Wait, what do you mean by "save that file"? You shouldn't make a *new* domain controller from the backup of a previous one. That's a recipe for disaster. You should only restore a dead DC from its own backup. Bare metal backups aren't the right way to "clone" a new domain controller. Should you never ever promote any Domain Controller that's from a cloned image and hasn't been sysprepped. Also, you're really asking things that are out of the scope of this question. **If you have a question about how to handle backups, ask a new question.**

Comment: Let me clarify. Since the domain controller is on a virtual machine image, can't I create a new virtual machine image, run all software updates, install the AD DS role, but don't promote it. Then use the VHD file as a master if I need to replace a bad domain controller virtual machine, run dc promo, and let it copy from the virtual machine of a different host running active directory?

Comment: @NoMoreDell4Me Not if you don't sysprep it. You should never deploy any cloned Windows image that hasn't been sysprepped. Ever. Not just for Domain Controllers.

Comment: I thought I read in one of the MS articles it was possible without mention of sysprep.

Comment: Sorry, but this is really outside the scope of your original question (and also a bad idea to do). If you really want to know the answer about how to back up a Hyper-V host, or how to properly clone servers in Hyper-V, please ask new questions for each topic.

Comment: Domain controllers are the only thing it's 100% necessary to run sysprep; everything else is just highly recommended (like asking for trouble if you don't). Installing Windows on a VM and getting it to DC status shouldn't take more than 1 hour, so not much point in "being prepared". As MDMarra stated, your only recovery strategy should be backups of the two DCs via full VM backup and System State.

Answer (score 2):

I've been doing it at my company for several years, and it's worked quite well for us.

Microsoft has some articles published ([here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd363553%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) and [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/888794)) that you should probably read.

The biggest suggestion I have is that you shouldn't do a P2V conversion of existing domain controllers. Instead, create a fresh VM with windows installed, and do a DCPromo on it, then decommission the old DC, remembering to move the FSMO rules.

Comment: Our physical machine that we have now needs to be replaced. So I currently have two physical servers with Hyper-v installed. I created the VM on each and will do a dcpromo. Then demote the old server. This way the DC are on two physical servers inside their own VM.

Comment: If you need HA for your VM's in case of a host failure then you should install Failover Clustering on your Hyper-V hosts (you'll need shared storage and a quorum disk or file share). In the case of your DC's you can configure them to have "affinity" for a particular Hyper-V host or you can configure them to failover to and failback from the other Hyper-V host if one of the hosts fail.

Comment: Server 2008 R2 standard doesn't seem to support failover clustering.

Comment: It doesn't. Sorry, I didn't catch which edition you were running.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can have domain controllers as virtual machines on a Hyper-V host.  I would not recommend that they be your *only* domain controllers though. Physical machines are preferable for domain controllers in my opinion. Also, don't snapshot and restore virtual machine Domain Controllers like you would with other VMs. That can cause USN rollbacks and lingering objects.

So yes, you can do that. Definitely if it's a lab or development environment. But for a serious production environment I would suggest some physical DCs.

Comment: Why do you say that "Physical machines are preferable for domain controllers"? -- A properly configured VMWare cluster with high availability will give you substantially more reliable DCs than you can get with physical hardware.  The only caveats I'm aware of are the snapshot/restore issue you've mentioned, and potentially time issues if your hypervisor has issues with keeping guest clocks sane.

Comment: That's why I said "in my opinion." I like my physical DCs. I understand that a virtualized domain controller is a perfectly acceptable and supported thing to do, but I mean within the context of this question, the OP only appears to have a single host, not a cluster. You can also mix and match, like having one physical DC, and a virtualized DC for redundancy.